# How do I position a Silverlight Control

Tags: html, css, silverlight

I guess this is going to sound like a pretty basic question to any web developers out there, but HTML and CSS are not really my thing and I'm on a really steep learning curve, so please cut me a little slack.

I have a silverlight control the I've developed with some animated graphics that I need to position at the bottom right hand corner of a web page. Try as I might, I can't get the Silverlight stuff to show up how I want it.

The web site is based on the ASP.Net 'eCommerce' template, which uses the 'Jello Mould' layout technique. This template has three colums, the main content colum is in the centre and is resizable horizontally. I want to position my Silverlight control in the bottom right hand corner of this column, and have it render beneath the HTML content (so I'll use the 'Windowless' parameter).

How can I achieve this positioning, please?

Oh, and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a div round the Silverlight control, name the div, and use css to give that div a fixed height (height:150px) and width (width:250px) (both being the width and height of the SIlverlight control), make it (position:absolute) and add a (bottom:0px) and (right:0px) to the div class properties (adjust the 0px to the number of pixels you want to let the control stand out).

Cannot try this out now (I'm not at my development pc), but I would look in this direction.